# RestFul Java With JaxRs 404 Found

Tags: java, rest, tomcat7, jax-rs

I am making small application. I think I made everything correctly but I got 404 error. Please be honest and see my code https://github.com/chalauri/Tsu_Junior and tell me if anything is incorrect. I deployed my application on tomcat. the module path is "/" and for example I got 404 `http://localhost:8080/tsu/faculty/test` from this url

Comment: Put code here on SO rather than an external site - paste in the code where you think you may have your error.

Comment: I don't know where is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

One issue I see (but probably not the only one); It looks like you are trying to access a method in the FacultyResource class, but there is no method with a path of test or a path parameter in that class.

Try adding a method with path test

```
@Path("/test")
@GET
public String testMethod(){

    return "Hello World";
}
```

Or add a method with a path param

```
@Path("/{name}")
@GET
public String testMethod(@PathParam("name") String name){

    return "Hello " + name;
}
```